# Spring configuration

Tags: java, spring

Let's say we have a bean definition in spring configuration

```
<bean id="scanningIMAPClient" class="com.acme.email.incoming.ScanningIMAPClient" />
```

What I really want is the scanningIMAPClient to be of type com.acme.email.incoming.GenericIMAPClient if the configured email server is a normal IMAP server and com.acme.email.incoming.GmailIMAPClient incase it is a GMAIL server, (since gmail behaves in slightly different way) GmailIMAPClient is a subclass of GenericIMAPClient.

How can I accomplish that in spring configuration?

There is a properties file which contains configuration of the email server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple with Java configuration:

```
@Value("${serverAddress}")
private String serverAddress;

@Bean
public GenericIMAPClient scanningIMAPClient() {
    if(serverAddress.equals("gmail.com"))
        return new GmailIMAPClient();
    else
        return new GenericIMAPClient();
}
```

You can emulate this behaviour with custom [`FactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use programatic configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean(name="scanningIMAPClient")
    public GenericIMAPClient helloWorld() {
        ...check config and return desired type
    }

}
```

More info [here](http://www.springsource.org/javaconfig).